# Html selected issue with ajax/jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've a html form where the countries in the drop down are coming from a database. If user selects any country, then the city drop diwn will appear based on selected country.

If user wrongly input any field of the form (there are other field in this form) then country drop down will will remember which country the user initially selected, but clears the city, resetting it to `--Select City--`. I'm trying to selected the **city name** but I can't. Any idea ?

**Ajax Code here:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/
ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".country").change(function()
{
var id=$(this).val();
var dataString = 'id='+ id;

$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax_city.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$(".city").html(html);
} 
});

});
});
</script>
```

**ajax_city.php here**

```
<?php
require_once("toplevel/content/database/databd.php");
if($_POST['id'])
{
$id=$_POST['id'];
$sql=mysql_query("select Name from cities WHERE CountryCode ='$id'");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$id=$row['Code'];
$data=$row['Name'];

if($_POST['city'] == $data)
{
    $sel = 'selected = "selected"'; 
}
else
{
    $sel = " ";
}

echo '<option value="'.$data.'" ' .$sel . ' >'.$data.'</option>';
} 
}
?>
```

**Html form here:**

```
<tr>
    <td>PAYS <span style="color: #FF0000;">*</span></td>
    <td>
<select name="country" class="country">
<option value="">Select</option>

<?php
    $sql=mysql_query("select * from country");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
    $id=$row['Code'];
    $data=$row['Name'];

    $data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8');

if($id == $_POST['country'])
    {
        $sel = 'selected="selected"';
    }
    else
    {
        $sel = "";
    }

    echo '<option value="'.$id.'"' . $sel . '>'.$data.'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>   
</td>
</tr>   

<tr>
<td>City</td>
    <td>
    <select class="city" name="city">
<option selected="selected" value="">--Select City--</option>
</select>   
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: county list is getting populated or not?

Comment: @Jai country list is populated.

Comment: all is ok, but when user wrongly input any filed then country is selected but city is not.

Comment: Let me check if I get this right:  

Everything works correctly, except when the user inputs an invalid value in another (unrelated) field, one that is not shown in your code.  When the user clicks the submit button, the page submits and repaints, however, with an error.  Now you would like to display the city user previously selected.

Comment: @BabuAhmed - If that's the case, look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure but issue is in `datastring` try changing this:

```
 $(".country").change(function(){
     var id=$(this).val();
     var dataString = {'id': id};

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_city.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
           $(".city").html(html);
        } 
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to rebuild your HTML on reload, but now with your City list (this is untested, but based on your code from the Country dropdown):

```
<tr>
    <td>City</td>
    <td>
        <select class="city" name="city">
            <option selected="selected" value="">--Select City--</option>
            <?php
                if (isset($_POST['city']) {
                    $sql=mysql_query("select * from city");
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                    {
                        $id=$row['Code'];
                        $data=$row['Name'];

                        $data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8');

                        if($id == $_POST['city']) { $sel = 'selected="selected"'; }
                        else { $sel = ""; }

                        echo '<option value="'.$id.'"' . $sel . '>'.$data.'</option>';
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </select>   
    </td>
</tr>
```

WARNING: This is just same sample code.  This should never ever go into production, because it has the potential for being extremely unsafe!  As @PolishPrince has pointed out above, you should at least use PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: What do you mean? Was it working before? If so, what changes did you make? What does "not working" mean? Why accept this answer and then unaccept?